# How to obtain a OpenId Identifier from Google

Tags: internet, openid

I'm trying to create an account at [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/users/openid) using OpenId.  It's asking for an "OpenId Identifier".  I read [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/45992/get-openid-from-google-or-microsoft), but it doesn't really show how to actually get the identifier.  I looked all over my Gmail settings.

EDIT:  I found the `www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` (long code) in my SuperUser profile.  Commandlinefu just says "OpenID login failed".  What am I supposed to put there?

Comment: @John-T has your answer, unfortunately, but you should be able to use an alternate (such as the one you used to sign into this site?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think commandlinefu supports Google OpenIDs. They need to properly add it with the method shown [here](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html). When added, a link is provided that redirects to Google's login page and uses the login process shown here:

[image]

since their site lacks this, the method cannot be used.

Support for Google OpenIDs has been requested on [their uservoice](http://commandlinefu.uservoice.com/pages/11102-general/suggestions/289972-allow-users-to-sign-up-via-gmail-openid).

Comment: Thanks!  I just used a different openId provider and all is well.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following in the OpenID prompt:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
```

It will redirect to Google's auth service and if you are already logged in with your Google account then the login to the site using OpenID should be transparent.

Comment: did you give it a try?

Comment: As @John-T mentioned, commandlinefu doesn't support Google OpenIDs.  Sadly, I just lost 10 minutes thinking I was doing something wrong before reloading these new answers. haha  However, +1 anyway for providing what *would* be a correct answer. ;)

Comment: Also, for anyone who doesn't want to remember that ridiculous Google URL (their fault, not yours) there is a bit.ly synonym: http://bit.ly/gopenid

Comment: I get "OpenID login failed". As mentioned in another answer, there's a feature request.  The developer says he's working on it: http://commandlinefu.uservoice.com/forums/11102-general/suggestions/289972-allow-users-to-sign-up-via-gmail-openid

Comment: That was on march 18. Still no joy...

Comment: This answer should still be the accepted one. The URL provided works with many other OpenID products.

Comment: @DavidS unfortunately, it does not work with commandlinefu, which is OP's purpose...